# Powershell Search older files, rename and copy newer files to all found locations

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Tried to copy several files (newer version) from one location to several different locations (older version) based on search result. The search and rename worked fine; but copy didn't work. Just need a way to point the current search directory as -destination folder.

1. Search for older files (*DB2JCC*) in all locations C: & D: drivers
2. Rename files from DB2JCC* to OLD_DB2JCC*.*
3. Copy the new version DB2JCC* files to all step 2 (above step) locations

Script used -

### search for file name older than '2018-05-02' and replace with newer version files

```
Get-ChildItem C:\, D:\ -include '*db2jcc*' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt '2018-05-02' } | 
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace 'DB2JCC','Old_DB2JCC' }
ForEach-Object { Copy-Item 'C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\DB2JCC*.*' -Destination $ENV:Temp }
```

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks, Johnson

Comment: 2 things: 1.) You're trying to copy what you've renamed already. 2.) use double quotes.

Comment: your pipeline ENDS after the `Rename-Item` ... and nothing is sent to your `ForEach-Object`. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, good catch. Also, I've seen your comments on like 4 separate sites already lol

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - thank you! i am easily bored - and easily amused. so i wander around a bit ... [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks to Abraham and Lee_Dailey.  Do I need to add the | pipeline before ForEach-Object? Tried to add the | pipeline before ForEach-Object, but it failed with the Get-ChildItem : Access is denied; even I ran it as admin.  Any problem with the copy-Item -Destination $ENV:Temp? Since I'm not sure what to put for that current directory.    Thanks, Johnson

Comment: @Abraham - Tried double quotes but didn't work. The object is to rename the older version file to Old_* and then copy the new version file DB2JCC*.* to the target(random) directory. Just need to find the correct parameter for the target direction for -destination. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to copy the new files from `'C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\DB2JCC*.*'`, to the directories where you renamed the other files from? Also, is `DB2JCC*.*` a directory, or is that your way of trying to filter and copy all files that start with that?

Comment: and... is there multiple files in `C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\` with the beginning name of `DB2JCC`, or just one? If there are multiple, do they all need to be copied over to each individual directory as a group?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, Yes, there are multiple files starts with DB2JCC*.* (new version) in 'C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java that need to copy to each individual directory that has the same file name start with DB2JCC*.* (older version), so I just rename older version files to Old_DB2JCC*.*; before copy the new version DB2JCC*.* file to each individual directory.

Answer (score 0):

Based off your answer, you can try something a long the lines of this:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Paths = @()
Get-ChildItem C:\,D:\ -Filter "*db2jcc*" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt '2018-05-02' } | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $null = $Paths.Add($_.FullName)
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $_.Name.Replace('DB2JCC','Old_DB2JCC') -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } 
        
Foreach($Path in $Paths){
    $Path = $Path -replace '[^\\]+$'
    Copy-Item "C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\" -Filter "DB2JCC*" -Recurse -Destination $Path }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. Unfortunately, the Copy-Item still not work. The Get-ChildItem, Rename and current directory all worked; just the last step copy-Item not work.

Comment: add another loop!(:

Comment: Thanks much Abraham. It worked now. Really appreciated your help :-)